# Multiple databases in rails and failing migration to change a datatype

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using multiple databases in rails, which are selected by the subdomain.
However, If I upgrade a data type, lets say Invoice.sum, from integer to decimal, then the new Invoice.sum is decimal, but after connecting to one of the subdomain-databases it is integer again.

More specific:

**The migration**

`change_column :invoices, :sum, :decimal`

```
rake db:migrate
rake db:migrate_for_all_subdomain_databases
```

**Pseudo-code to reproduce:**

```
rails c
details = YAML::load(ERB.new(IO.read(yml_path)).result)['database_details']
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(details)
Invoice //sum IS INTEGER instead of decimal
```

But when I check the data type *before* connecting to the subdomain databases, it is decimal:

```
rails c
Invoice //sum is DECIMAL
details = YAML::load(ERB.new(IO.read(yml_path)).result)['database_details']
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(details)
Invoice //sum IS DECIMAL
```

I assume, that there is something in rails, which caches the schema for every activerecord connection. 
Does someone know hot to "refresh" it?

Thanks alot!

Comment: Nice setup! Have you got different DB's for different subdomains?